# gpsd:error: can't run with neither control socket nor devices on petalinux

Tags: ubuntu, gpsd, petalinux

I am facing a gpsd issues on petalinux. I have installed the gpsd on petalinux but the gpsd-client was not being installed, thats why  gpsd.socket and the gpsd.service files are missing. Can someone tell me if i add these files manually, where i place these files so that gpsd works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gpsd-client is a separate recipe.  It's not installed automatically when you install gpsd.  You'll need to explicitly call it out in your PetaLinux build.  That being said, gpsd is not dependent on gpsd-client so it should work whether gpsd-client is installed or not.

To install gpsd-client:
Open project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/images/petalinux-image.bbappend
(filename may vary based on version of Petalinux you are using)

add these lines:
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gpsd"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gpsd-client"

petalinux-config -c rootfs
user packages --> [x] gpsd
user packages --> [x] gpsd-client

petalinux-build

If gpsd-client fails to build correctly, you may need to [add the appropriate layer to the build process](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842475/PetaLinux+Yocto+Tips#PetaLinuxYoctoTips-WorkingwithaUserSpaceYoctoLayer).  The gpsd-client recipe info can be found in the [OpenEmbedded Layer Index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/136952/).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I have installed the gpsd on zynq zc7010 but when i run the gpsd or /etc/init.d/gpsd start command, then gpsd:ERROR: can't run with neither control socket nor devices occur. I don't know how can i rectify this error. Can you guide me a bit more

Comment: You need to tell it what device to use as an argument (e.g. gpsd -D 5 -N -n /dev/ttyUSB0)
Have you tried the steps here?: https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/installation.html

Comment: yes I tried every possible steps but the problem is still same.

Comment: Are you running as root?  Have you tried communicating directly with the GPS device to confirm it is working?